# template is not updating, while the directive is

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

On my `application.html.haml` I want to inject two templates: `_frontpage` and `_movieTemplate`

This is my home state,

```
.state('home', {
  url: '',
  views: {
    "frontpage": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_frontpage.html',
      controller: 'searchCtrl'
    },
    "movieoverview": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movieTemplate.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

And this is the code on the `application.html.haml`

```
%div{"ui-view" => "frontpage"}
%div{"ui-view" => "movieoverview"}
%movie-Overview
```

I have two `ui-view` elements. In here I inject the templates, this works fine. I also have a directive called `movie-Overview`

```
app
  .directive('movieOverview', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movieTemplate.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl',
    };
  });
```

As you can see the directive `movieOverview` does the same as the:

```
%div{"ui-view" => "movieoverview"}`
```

They share the same template `_movietemplate.html` and controller `addMovieCtrl`

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'release_date'"}
  .release_date_container
    %h2.release_date{"data-fittext" => ""}
      {{ movie.release_date }}

  .poster{"back-img" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.image }}"}
    %img{"ng-src" => "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{ movie.image }}"}

  .movie-info
    %h2.title
      {{ movie.title }}
    %a.delete{"ng-click" => "deleteMovie(movie)"}delete
```

So I wouldn't expect any difference in behaviour, but there is.

When a user adds a new record (a new movie) to the database, the directive does refresh its template and shows the new record in the view. But the `ui-view` does not, it only shows the new record in the view after a refresh.

So can someone explain why a directive that loads the same controller and template does update its view when a new record is added, and the ui-view does not?

Comment: do the partial and directive share the same controller? I see 'movieoverview'  belongs to addMovieCtrl.

Comment: Yes they have same `addMovieCtrl` controller. As you can see in the `home` state I asign the `addMovieCtrl` to the `movieoverview` view. And in the directive I asign the `addMovieCtrl` controller to the directive.

Comment: After a lot of trying I've seem to find the error. It seems you can't have one state with 2 views asign different controllers to them.

Comment: Are you using `ui-router`? According to the wiki of `ui-router`, each view in `views` can set up its own templates, controllers and resolve. [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)